# Jquery ajax post text in to txt

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

first of all sorry im a beginner.

Im making a small shoutbox with jquery just for practies

I would like to place the shoutbox text to a txt file with ajax.

but my problem is i wont insert it to the txt

the ajax

```
<script>
$('#submit').click(function() {

    var shout_text = $("input#shout_text").val();

    var shout = $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "shout.txt",
          data: shout_text,
          //success: success,
          dataType: "text",

});



});
</script>
```

could please someone point out what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
<script>
$('#submit').click(function() {

    var shout_text = $("input#shout_text").val();

    var shout = $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "shout.php",
          data: {message:shout_text},
          success: function(){ 

          }
});



});
</script>
```

you have to input $_POST['message'] into text file in your server-side (if you use PHP)

You can't just "send" text to your text file

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify a "message" header if you set the correct type (`dataType: "text"`):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "shout.php",
    method : "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    data: shout_text,
    success: function(){}
})
```

You can access it with `file_get_contents('php://input')` or in some memory-safe way.